# Is override the ‘Not authorized’ message in a Blazor Server App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

`[Authorize]` page is
[image]

I want customize that.

I cant find in scaffolding pages.

Visual studio 2022
.NET 6.0
Authentication type: Individual Accounts(ASP.NET Core Identity.)

Index.razor.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace BlazorServerApp.Pages
{
    [Authorize]
    public partial class Index
    {
    }
}
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

Index pages was created by vs 2022. I add `[Authorize]`.

Comment: I want 12 gold bars on my porch each morning but wanting does not seem to help me either.  Please post actual code of what you have tried and your one challenge that presents you.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I post source.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#customize-unauthorized-content-with-the-router-component):

modify App.razor:

```
<AuthorizeRouteView ...>
   <NotAuthorized>
        Your message           
   </NotAuthorized>                
</AuthorizeRouteView>
```

Message has been overrided:

[image]

And you could just add @attribute [Authorize] in your index.razor without the partial class in Index.razor.cs

Comment: It's very good!